# implementing redux in react native

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to implement `redux` to show balance in multiple screens as I update balance in single screen it should reflect in all other screens/components.

I'm pretty new to `redux`. As you know with complexity around redux, its even making difficult to implement it.

I followed some examples in GitHub and youtube and started implementing it .

under **Actions folder** I have. following two files

counteractions.js

```
  import * as types from './actionTypes.js';

//ActionCreator methods

export function updateBalance(balanceInfo) {

    return {
        type: types.LEDGER_BALANCE,
        payLoad: { balanceInfo }
    }
}
```

Under Reducers folder.I have this file

balance.js

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes.js';
    const initialState = {
        balance: 0
    }

    // reducer  functions .. accepts  current/initial state , actions and  returns new state



    const balanceReducer=(state,action)=>
    {
        switch (action.type) {
            case types.LEDGER_BALANCE:
                return {
                    balance: action.payload.balanceInfo
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    export default balanceReducer;
```

in ConfigureStore.js

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index.js';

    import balanceReducer from './reducers/balance.js';

    const initailState = {
        balance: 0,
    }

    export const store=createStore(balanceReducer,balanceReducer);
```

App.js

```
    /**
     * Sample React Native App
     * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
     * @flow
     */

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    //Provider - makes redux store  available to connect() class in component hierarchy below
    import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose, combineReducers } from "redux";
    import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
    import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
    import rootReducer from './reducers/index.js';
    //import store from './configureStore.js';

    import {
      Platform,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      TouchableOpacity,
      TextInput
    } from 'react-native';
    import ReduxDemo from "./reduxDemo.js";
    import { store, reducer } from './balanceDemo.js';

    const instructions = Platform.select({
      ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
      'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
      android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
      'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
    });

    export default class App extends Component<{}> {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          balancelocal: '',
        }
      }



      _updateLedger = () => {
        // store.dispatch({ type: 'BALANCE', payLoad: '500' });
        store.dispatch({ type: 'BALANCE', payLoad: 'Your balance is 8000 MUR' });
      }


      render() {

        store.subscribe(() => {

          this.setState({
            balancelocal: store.getState(),
          })
          //this.balanceInfo = store.getState().balance;
         // alert(this.state.balancelocal);
        });
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._updateLedger}>
              <Text>Update balance</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TextInput style={{height:100,width:400}} value={this.state.balancelocal}/>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

The styling for it

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

I'm yet to complete configure store file. and. I'm wondering,  where I have to subscribe and dispatch actions ...

**I want to update balance with button click from app.js 
I have. to update balance in another page automatically..**

Please guide me to understand and implement `redux` .Please suggest better folder structure and better way to implement `redux`.

Comment: Go through this link: https://hackernoon.com/redux-step-by-step-a-simple-and-robust-workflow-for-real-life-apps-1fdf7df46092

Answer (score 1):

https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist 
The above link has a basic setting up of react with redux. It is almost similar for React Native too.

You need to wrap your `App` component inside `Provider` imported from 'react-redux', and then give that to `AppRegistry`. Also you do not seem to have imported any actions and haven't used the connect function either. Like the comment above, it is better for you go through a video guide on basics of redux. It'll help you understand all the complexity, and once you understand, nothing is as easy as redux. All the best.